# Are high schools dumbing down their exams? I don't know. How can we find out?

Tags: time-series, panel-data, intervention-analysis

I have a large-ish longitudinal dataset of high school and college course registration and grades. I want to test the assertion that high schools are "dumbing down" their courses to meet graduation quotas, resulting in "poorly prepared" college students.

The dataset includes course info and numerical grade (%) for every student registration in high school and college.

- What could we observe in the data that would increase / decrease the probability of the assertion being true? What methodology could allow us to observe that?
- What if the college professors are also dumbing down their own exams as a result of the students being unprepared for higher education? Could we still detect a possible inflation of high school grades then?

Comment: You have to address confounding with different teachers (among other things).  Depending on the particulars of your dataset, if you did find some difference in grades over time, how would you know if this is the result of some potential "dumbing down" versus a different set of teachers with different teaching philosophy?  Are you controlling for teacher in some meaningful way?  In addition, how can you rule out improvements or degradation in curriculum as implemented by state or national standards?

Comment: You could try to correlate high school success to college success as a trend over time. The concern that colleges also vary in both selectiveness and difficulty over time is well founded. You could never overcome such a bias without having a standardized (age invariant) aptitude test that could be administered to people of varying educational cohorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you have is enough to examine how high-school and college grades vary over time, but not to distinguish changes in student ability from changes in test difficulty. To do that, you'd need some other measure of student ability or test difficulty. You may be interested in reading studies of the [Flynn effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn_effect), which is the finding that humans in general have gotten smarter over the last century or so.

Comment: More precisely, the Flynn effect is the secular increase of test *scores*. There is much discussion in the psychometric literature whether this also means that people actually have gotten *smarter*. Many argue they have not (e.g by arguing that the increase is not on *g*).